# iptables-restore failed in Debian buster/sid if it has --multiport option in the rules file

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, netfilter, iptables-persistent

I have `/etc/iptables/rule.v4` file contains many rule, the below is the line where I see the issue

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 16384:32768 -j ACCEPT
```

When I tried to do `iptables-restore` it failed with below error

```
root@rs-dal:/etc/iptables# iptables-restore rules.q
iptables-restore v1.8.2 (nf_tables): multiport needs `-p tcp', `-p udp', `-p udplite', `-p sctp' or `-p dccp'
Error occurred at line: 26
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
root@rs-dal:/etc/iptables#
```

why is it failing?, the same rule had worked successfully on `Debian Jessie`.

Also when I changed the rules like below, it worked.

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 16384:32768 -j ACCEPT
```

I checked the `iptables -L` and these rules applied successfully as below

```
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpts:16384:32768
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
```

Whether the rule that I currently have is a valid syntax?

Below is my OS details

```
root@rs-dal:/etc/iptables# cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: Is the line you are talking about the offending line? Line 26?

Comment: yes the line 26 is `-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Are you saving the rules via `iptables-save > rules.q` and restoring with `iptables-restore < rules.q`? I just tested with your exact rules on Debian 9.

Comment: I have the rules.q with me, so I am not running `iptables-save`, I am restoring the rules with `iptables-restore rules.q`. In Debian 9, it works fine, the issue is only with Debian 10 (Buster).

Comment: Can you manually add that rule? Removing that rule from your save file, manually adding it, saving the file again and seeing if it can be restored again.

Comment: Awesome, it worked fine. but what could be the issue when I have the exact same rule specified in the pre-existing file?

Comment: Perhaps something went wrong when the file was converted to STDOUT. If you want I can either draft the answer for this post, or you can post the exact steps you took to solve your issue and accept it.

Comment: The credit should go to you, so please draft the answer and post it. I will accept it. Basically the last 2 of your comments is the answer.

Comment: There's the difference on buster/sid: iptables is running over nftables, as seen in your version: `iptables-restore v1.8.2` **`(nf_tables)`** . If you can reproduce a file *made from* an `iptables-*-save`, not manually, where using `iptables-legacy-restore` works but not `iptables-nft-restore`, that might be a parsing bug.

Comment: Will test and update, whether it works with `iptables-nft-restore` and `iptables-legacy-restore`

Comment: I have a file that was created manually and that works fine with `iptables-legacy-restore` and failed with `iptables-nft-restore`, I have another file created using `iptables-legacy-save` which works fine for both `iptables-legacy-restore` and `iptables-nft-restore`. As mentioned by @kemotep it could be STDOUT issue. Thanks @A.B for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user A.B. points out there is an issue with incompatibility between `nftables`, which Buster uses, and `iptables`.   The best way to save `iptables` rules to be restored with `iptables-restore` between compatible versions.

Remove the offending line, and restore the rules:

```
iptables-restore < rules.q
```

Re-add the rule to your configuration and save:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables-save > rules.q
```

Now try restoring again:

```
iptables-restore < rules.q
```

Use `iptables -L` to verify all of your rules are in place.